# Regex multiple lookaheads not working when both are triggered

Tags: php, regex, laravel, regex-lookarounds

I am creating a username field with Laravel and I'm using RegEx to set the formatting rules.
The rule is: Not only numbers **AND OR** underlines + only numbers, chars, and underlines are allowed in general.

Now I came up with this RegEx syntax:
`(?!^\d+$)^.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`

This works fine until the point where I input stuff like:
*____2348734*

How can I prevent that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of

```php
^(?![\d_]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
^(?![\d_]+$)\w+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mOM7qg/1). Also, consider using `\z` instead of `$` to disallow a trailing newline input.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![\d_]+$)`  - the string cannot only contain digits / underscores
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` / `\w+` - one or more alphanumeric or `_` chars
- `$`  - end of string. (`\z` will match the very end of string.)